# How to replicate Pandas syntax? (To filter data frames)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, syntax, pythonista

How do I implement the syntax for filtering dataframes in Pandas? (`df[df.column1 > someValue]`)

I am trying to make a class that have the same syntax of Pandas when filtering dataframes.

How do I replicate the syntax for a Dataframe `df = DataFrame(someData)`  like this one:

```
df[df.column1 > someValue]
```

I implemented the methods `__getattr__` and `__getitem__` for the syntaxes of

```
df.column1 
df['column1']
```

But I don't know how to link both together. Also, I could not find the function to copy from Pandas code.

Either an implementation to this problem or the reference to the function in Pandas would be of great help.

**Edit**:(Solution)

Following the hint on the answers I implemented the `__getitem__` function as follows:

```
from tier tools import compress

def __getitem__(self, name):
    """Get items with [ and ]
    """
    #If there is no expression, return a column
    if isinstance(name, str):
      return self.data[name]

    #if there was an expression return the dataframe filtered
    elif isinstance(name, list):
      ind = list(compress(range(len(name)), name))
      temp = DataFrame([[self.data[c].values[i] 
                            for i in ind] 
                           for c in self.columns],
                           columns=self.columns)
      return temp
```

Note that I also had to implement the comparison methods for my column class (Series). 
The full code can be seen [here](https://github.com/mauhcs/pagode/blob/master/pagode.py).

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `__getitem__` to take a list of booleans and only return items when `True`. You will also need to implement the conditional operators (`>`, `==`, etc.) to return that list of booleans, e.g. (proof of concept code):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return A([d for k, d in zip(key, self.data) if k])
    def __gt__(self, value):
        return [d > value for d in self.data]
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.__class__) + ' [' + ', '.join(str(d) for d in self.data) + ']'

>>> a = A(list(range(20)))
>>> a
<class '__main__.A'> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> a[a > 5]
<class '__main__.A'> [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you basically want something that just wraps a [recarray or structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).

```
import numpy as np

myarray = np.array([("Hello",2.5,3),
                        ("World",3.6,2),
                        ('Foobar',2,7)]).T

df = np.core.records.fromarrays(myarray, 
                             names='column1, column2, column3',
                             formats = 'S8, f8, i8')

print(df)
print(df[df.column3<=3])
```

While I don't use Pandas myself, the DataFrame seems like it is very similar to a recarray.  If you wanted to roll your own, be sure to read about [subclassing ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html).  numpy arrays can also be indexed with boolean mask variables such as

```
myarray = np.array([(1,2.5,3.),
                        (2,3.6,2.),
                        (3,2,7.)])
print(myarray[myarray[:,2]<=3.])
```